# Problems with spring-test-mvc on Jenkins with Sonar

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, jenkins, sonarqube

I have recently discovered Spring project for MVC testing: [spring-test-mvc](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc). It's a great tool, and I plan to use it more in the future.

However I have noticed a problem with it on my Jenkins CI. The problem is that while MVC integration tests are passing locally, and even on Jenkins CI job, the problem occurs in the Jenkins' Sonar plugin execution. In this case all asserts done with ".andExpect()" method I tried fail. Yes, they pass if Sonar plugin is not used.

For example

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/someController/some.action").param("someParam", "someValue"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(request().sessionAttribute("someAttribute", notNullValue()));
```

In the above test content type and session attribute assertions are failing.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have created an issue on this topic, more details can be found [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc/issues/34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by kind people from spring-mvc. More details can be found on the provided [link](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc/issues/34). In short, in my case Sonar uses Cobertura for coverage testing.

> Cobertura adds the interface `HasBeenInstrumented` and because of that
>   the class is decorated as a JDK dynamic proxy instead, which means a
>   synthetic proxy class with one interface that's not very helpful since
>   it's a Cobertura marker interface. As a result and the controller can
>   never and no annotations can be properly discovered.

The problem is solved by adding `proxy-target-class="true"` to `<tx:annotation-driven>` element

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. We upgraded the Cobertura jar version to the latest. This change made the JUnit testcases to run in local as well as in Jenkins